# Clear Focus of Clicked Word in TextView

Tags: android, onclick, textview, focus, motionevent

I am using a customized `LinkMovementMethod` Class to customize my text `onClick` that works very well but as it click the `Clickable` word it remains pressed  as show

[image]

how could I release it

Also here is the custom class I use

```
public abstract class TextViewLinkHandler extends LinkMovementMethod {

private String text;

public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
    y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

    x += widget.getScrollX();
    y += widget.getScrollY();

    Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
    int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
    int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

    URLSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off, URLSpan.class);

    CharSequence charSequence = widget.getText();
    if (charSequence instanceof Spannable) {
        Spannable spannableText = (Spannable)charSequence;
        ClickableSpan[] spans = spannableText.getSpans(0, widget.length(), ClickableSpan.class);
        for (ClickableSpan span55555 : spans) {
            int start55555 = spannableText.getSpanStart(span55555);
            int end55555 = spannableText.getSpanEnd(span55555);
            Log.i("tessst", String.valueOf(charSequence.subSequence(start55555, end55555)));
            text = String.valueOf(charSequence.subSequence(start55555, end55555));
        }
    }

    if (link.length != 0) {
        onLinkClick(link[0].getURL(),TextViewLinkHandler.this.text);
        widget.invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}

abstract public void onLinkClick(String url,String text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer but hopefully it might still help someone.

These are my findings (compileSdk/targetSdk 33, running on API 33):

- `postInvalidate()` on the `TextView` works but the link won't highlight again if clicked a second time without first tapping outside the link.
- `view.isVisible = false; view.isVisible = true` on the `TextView` works if called in a `view.post{}` block but the link won't highlight again if clicked a second time without first tapping outside the link.
- Setting the same text with a new `Spannable` on the `TextView` removes the highlight and it works also when clicked a second time.

I could not get clearFocus() to work even with a focusable parent or sibling.